# Yii2 kartik-v select2 widget allowClear and placeholder not working properly

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using the advanced template of Yii2.  Whenever the select2 'placeholder' is assigned a value, the widget won't show the initial value.  I can work around this by using `['placeholder' => $placeholder]` and setting the variable to NULL whenever an initial value exists.  However, if the placeholder is NULL and an initial value is showing, then allowClear doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

View:

```
use kartik\select2\Select2;

<?= $form->field($profile, 'associationSelect')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $associationList,
    'language' => 'en',
    'theme' => 'krajee',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Association ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
])->label(''); ?>
```

Controller:

```
$associationArray = Association::find()                                             
    ->select('association, id')
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->orderBy('association')
    ->all(); 
$associationList = ArrayHelper::map($associationArray, 'id', 'association');
```

$associationList is an array like {[1]=>"association1", [2]=>"association2, [3] ..."}.
`$profile->associationSelect` is prepopulated by the controller with a key.  My problem is that the widget always shows 'Select Association ...' whether `$profile->associationSelect` is populated or not.  I only want the placeholder to show if `$associationSelect` is empty, as that's how a placeholder is supposed to work.  And if I leave placeholder empty (NULL), the clear option ("x") shows up in the widget, but won't clear the text (i.e. it doesn't do anything when clicked).

Comment: As a side comment. I do not use that widget, I prefer to use regular dropdownlist with prompt for first value, add class "select2" and use this library: https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/LICENSE.md. Any advantage to use kartik-v's one?

Comment: @Eduardo It looks like the same one.  The Kartik widget provides a Yii2 wrapper for select2.  See https://github.com/select2/select2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that 'associationSelect' is an internal attribute rather than a db attribute. I switched to a db attribute and it works just fine.

```
<?= $form->field($profile, 'association')->widget(Select2::classname(), [                         
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Association::find()->orderBy('id')->all(), 'id', 'association'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'theme' => 'krajee',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select ...',],
    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
])->label(''); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I either didn't completely understand your question or I think I have solved your problem with only a few changes. I have put here several different things so you might not need some of them.

```
/*
 * $profile->associationSelect: data list and assigned default value by key: 2 (third element).
 * With this line, your select2 will have a default chosen value from data list.
 * Remove this (1) line to show placeholder instead.
 */
if (!empty($associationList)) {
    $form->associationSelect = 2; 
    echo $form->field($profile, 'associationSelect')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $associationList,
        'language' => 'en',
        'theme' => 'krajee',
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => $associationList[3] // Placeholder will show 4th element from data list (we do have a list)
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]);
} else {
    echo $form->field($profile, 'associationSelect')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $associationList,
        'language' => 'en',
        'theme' => 'krajee',
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Please select a value' // Placeholder will be default text since we don't have a list.
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]);
}
```

You may choose which option you want (whether with default selected value or just with placeholder). In both cases you can use `allowClear` and you won't get any errors (if done correctly, of course).

Comment: That's not how I understand placeholder to work.  Of course, I could be wrong :-).  I want placeholder to show "Select Association ...", unless $profile->associationSelect is pre-populated with a value from the database, in which case it should show that value and give me the option to clear it.  If I implement placeholder as you have shown above, it will display the correct value, but the text will be a light grey and I don't get the clear option, because it is, after all, only a placeholder.  See my updated code above.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SM0827 If I understood correctly, your data contains only 2 options (with keys 1 or 2) and you want to show one of them if that list is not empty? Which one eould you like?

Comment: @SM0827 I have edited my answer. This will check if we have a data list and if so, then set default value (selected), otherwise, it will show placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  I use several of these widgets in my application and the data array can contain varying numbers of items.  I can already do what you have shown above without having an if...else statement simply by setting ['placeholder' => $placeholder], and assign $placeholder either with the initial value, or 'Select Value ...' in the controller.  If the widget is working properly I shouldn't need to use an if...then statement.  Besides, I am still left with the problem in my comment above - i.e. the allowClear doesn't work.

Comment: @SM0827 Well, I don't know other solutions in here, then. For me it works fine. Maybe it's something with your data list? When I put bad data in that list, AllowClear is not working for me either.

Comment: I was thinking that could be the case.  I'm using array map and var_dump spits out the array as I show it in my question.  I'll mess with it some more and see.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @SM0827 you should provide how you pass your data list. In that case I would be able to see what can I do.

Comment: @SM0827 I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you any further because I tried what you wrote here (in updated version) and I still get all values in dropdown (and I can reset it). It might be possible that somewhere else is the problem. How about checking array with `var_dump($associationList);`? Maybe you don't get any values at all.

Comment: I do get values in the array as expected. At least I think I can rule out the array as the issue based on your comments.   I appreciate your help on this!

Comment: I upvoted, but my problem isn't fixed, so I can't accept the answer.

Comment: @SM0827 We may have to move to chat to discuss further solutions